# Need click event to trigger alert during else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, this code is working:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var btn = $('#submit_send_order');
  btn.attr({disabled: 'disabled'});
  var chk = $('.end-box');
  chk.click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('checked'))
      btn.removeAttr('disabled');
    else
      btn.attr({disabled:'disabled'});
  });
});
</script>
```

but I can't get any working version of a click, onclick, or event handler to cause a popup message during the else condition. Unless users checks a box, they cannot send their order on my site. Right now they click the button and nothing happens until they check the box. But I'd like an alert to show as well, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit_send_order').click(function(){
    alert("You cannot proceed until you check the end box");
  });
});
```

Comment: replace all instances of `attr` with `prop` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onclick event doesn't fire when the element is disabled. Also, notice which is the right method to see if the checkbox is checked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var btn = $('#submit_send_order');
  btn.attr({disabled: 'disabled'});
  var chk = $('.end-box');
  chk.on('click', function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      btn.removeAttr('disabled');
    else
      btn.attr({disabled:'disabled'});
  });
    btn.on('click', function(){
    alert("You cannot proceed until you check the end box");
  });
});
```

---

I build a "solution" for this if you REALLY whant to do that. You can check it at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2f1wsb8c/3/

It's placing an element with the same size of the button over it to catch the click when the button is disabled.

Comment: your example works, but when I implement the code on my site, I do not get a click response on the div and even when the box is checked I cannot click the submit button. Here is the actual HTML for the button:   `<input id="submit_send_order" style="vertical-align:middle;margin-bottom:4px;border:0px;margin-bottom:expression('7px');" type="image" src="img/review_continue.gif" value=" Send Order >>" alt=" Send Order >>" onclick="temp_disabled(this, 60)" disabled="disabled">`

Comment: @JacobIRR you are changing a lot of stuff there. Notice in my fiddle the style applied to the button:  position:relative;top:-20px;z-index:1. Now you also change the type to "image". Then you'll have to change the style of the div that catches the click and shows up on the button (now image) when the button is disabled. The principle is simple: positionate an element over the clickable input when it's disabled to show an alert message, and hide that element when the clickable button is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As Verhaeren said above, if the button is disabled, then it can't fire the click event.  Rather than disabling the button, I would just put an if/else check in the click event.

So...

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_send_order', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($('.end-box').prop('checked')) {
        //Handle form submission
    } else {
        alert('You cannot proceed until you check the end box');
    }
});
```